# add Office.onReady() function to javascript

Tags: javascript, office-js

I am new to Javascript and am trying to make an outlook web-addin take the `Office.onReady()` function properly.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/initialize-add-in

I tried using

```
Office.onReady()
    .then
```

to make my function work with the office js API but it then I got an error that my function couldn't be found.

Code:

```
$("#brief-summary").click(briefsummary);
$("#email-setup").click(emailsetup);

Office.onReady()
    .then(function briefsummary() {
  var msgFrom = Office.context.mailbox.item.from;
  var msgfirstname = String(msgFrom.displayName).split(" ");
  Office.context.mailbox.item.displayReplyAllFormAsync(
    "Hello " +
      msgfirstname[0] +
      ", <br> \
  <br> Here is a brief summary on everything worked on: \
    <br> \
    <br>Thank you for your time, \
      <br>"
  );
});
```

Result:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: briefsummary is not defined
```

So I am pretty sure I am doing it wrong.
I also tried using `Office.onReady();` at the begining of the script. It suppressed the `Uncaught Error: Office.js has not fully loaded. Your app must call "Office.onReady()"` error but office javascript doesn't do anything. (Its suppose to bring up a new reply window with text inside)

Link to where the app is hosted: https://alloyautomateaddinbeta3.azurewebsites.net/index.html (Although the office.js only loads when you are in the outlook app. But you can go to `sources` from inspector in chrome and look at the js script in full)
Any ideas would be awesome.

Comment: Try moving the out the declaration of briefsummary to a be a peer of  onReady and then shorten the call of onReady to `Office.onReady().then(briefsummary());`

Comment: Please note that the named function in your code snippet isn't supported.

Comment: I apologize as I don't know what you mean by this.  (I understand more python than javascript, this my first project with javascript) I was able to figure out my issue with the answer below some days ago but if you have a better way or want to explain in detail let me know. So far everything is working great.

Answer (score 0):

I have seems to figure out what to do but I was pretty janky. If anyone knowas a better way to clean this up let me know.

I essentially my code inbetween this and it worked:

```
Office.onReady((info) => {
  if (info.host === Office.HostType.Outlook) {

#Insert code here

}
});
```

It was pretty janky as it gives me a warning saying `Function variables should not be placed in blocks. Use a function expression or move the statement to the top of the outer function`

I will be working on the code periodically so I will update my answer to a better one as time goes on unless someone else has an answer as well.

Thanks